# Custom posts with multiple terms only being returned once

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type `products` which has the taxonomy `range`. 
I have another custom post type `stockist` which uses an ACF `post_object` to associate a product with a stockist.

I'm trying to loop through the stockist posts, return the title of each term and then a list of each product associated with the stockist through the post object.

```
<?php                           
$args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'stockist', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$stockistloop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): while ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): $stockistloop2->the_post();?>
<div class="col-1-1 clearfix nopad stockist-block-dropdown STORE <?php the_title();?>">
    <h2 class="stockist-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
<?php 
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'range');
$categories = get_categories($args);
 if($categories): foreach($categories as $category): $url = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>
    <div class="col-1-5 mobile-col-1-2">
        <h4><?php echo ($category->name) ;?></h4>
        <?php $post_objects = get_field('stocked_range'); if( $post_objects ): ?>
        <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
        <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): $post_terms_array = get_the_terms($post_object, 'range'); $post_term_name = $post_terms_array[0]->slug; 
            if($post_term_name == $category->slug):?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php  endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif;?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

This works to a point but where a product has more than one term. For example pork sausage might have the term "sausages" as well as "bbq", it's only returned once under sausages rather than being returned under both terms.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies with these lines:

```
$post_term_name = $post_terms_array[0]->slug;
if($post_term_name == $category->slug):
```

You're comparing every `$category` in the loop with only the first term associated with the product. Try this (I edited formatting a bit just for my own clarity).

```
<?php                           
$args2 = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'stockist', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);
$stockistloop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): while ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): $stockistloop2->the_post();
?>
<div class="col-1-1 clearfix nopad stockist-block-dropdown STORE <?php the_title();?>">
    <h2 class="stockist-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <?php 
    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'range'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    if($categories): 
    foreach($categories as $category): 
    $url = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
    ?>
    <div class="col-1-5 mobile-col-1-2">
        <h4><?php echo ($category->name); ?></h4>
        <?php 
        $post_objects = get_field('stocked_range'); 
        if( $post_objects ): 
        ?>
        <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
            <?php 
            foreach( $post_objects as $post_object ): 
            $post_terms_array = get_the_terms($post_object, 'range'); 
            $post_terms_id_array = wp_list_pluck( $post_terms_array, 'term_id' );
            if( in_array( $category->term_id, $post_terms_id_array ) ):
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php 
            endif;
            endforeach; 
            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    endforeach; 
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif; 
?>
```

I'm creating an array of just term IDs, then checking if the current `$category` ID is in that array.

Comment: Thanks johnnyd23. Going through the code I'd realised that's where I'd gone wrong but it'd have taken me hours to come up with a solution! Thanks for your help.